# Cómo puedo crear un array de nombres en c?

Tags: c

Tenía una duda sobre como podría crear una *array* de nombres, en el que podrías introducir los nombres con un `scanf`, y poder invocarlos de nuevo.

Por ejemplo en *bash* podrías hacer esto `test_array=(apple orange lemon)` y guardarías en `test_array[0] = apple`, `test_array[1] = orange` y `test_array[2] = lemon`. Querría hacer algo similar en c. Gracias de antemano por su atención.

Comment: ¿Sabes algo de c? Porque no es un tema complicado y hay montones de ejemplos en Tnternet. Empieza con uno y sube el código de lo que no te funcione o tengas dudas.

Comment: En C deberías usar una matriz de caracteres.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto es parecido a lo que quieres hacer, espero que te sirva:

```
#include "string.h"


#define MAXLEN 100

typedef char cadena[MAXLEN];

int main()
{
    char c;
    cadena array[20];
    printf("Hola mundo");

    strcpy(array[0], "HOLA");
    strcpy(array[1], "FIN");
    printf("%s, %s ", array[0], array[1]);
    scanf("%c", &c);
    return 0;
}
```